# How to make a drawn TileOverlay invisible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have an Android Maps v2 TileOverlay that works great.  I have my own TileProvider that generates bitmaps, everything works great.  I want to dynamically make the tile invisible some time at runtime, using code like this:

```
private TileOverlay tileOverlay;
...
tileOverlay = googleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
                .zIndex(100f)
                .tileProvider(new MyTileProvider(credential,mContext)));
...
tileOverlay.setVisible(false);
```

The TileProvider works and draws the tile just right, but the tile never goes invisible when I use `setVisible(false)`.

I can even read `tileOverlay.isVisible()` and it returns false, but the tile is still visible.

Is it possible to make a drawn tile invisible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can make a simple example that shows it, I'd suggest posting an issue on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2). Try adding `setVisible(false)` in Maps API demos TileOverlay example (the one showing moon).

Comment: Thanks MaciejGorski, great idea.  I did it and it works in the API demos. There they use a UrlTileProvider, whereas I define my own TileProvider.  I would have thought that the output TileOverlay of either would be the same, since they both work, but still, I can't make my own tile invisible, but I can make theirs invisible.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bug, I have started an issues in gmaps-api-issues 5541

Comment: Yes. If it works when using `clear` and not when `remove` or `setVisible` this is clearly a bug.

Comment: It would be great if you could star the issue also, thanks

Comment: I did star it that already. It would be great if you also could post your research in an answer here and accept it, so people having the same issue find an answer easily and those searching for questions to answer don't enter this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make a drawn TileOverlay invisible.  The bug was in my code:  I had removed the null check on the GoogleMap, which is called during both the Activity's onCreate() and onResume(), and therefore had multiple maps. So even after calling TileOverlay.setVisible(false) or .remove(), there were still other maps with the TileOverlay remaining.  The strange thing is that even without this null check the app seems to work in every other way.  See the important null check below:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (googleMap==null) {  //-- DON'T FORGET THIS!!

            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (googleMap!=null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```